# Google font Raleway Dots shows only Raleway on chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, fonts

for some reason on my website when i put a title font with Raleway Dots, it displays Raleway on chrome instead. On firefox works just fine.

I tried to import the font manually, use the !important on the class and directly on the tag and still doesn't work...

Problem: http://caisderio.com/quinta-para-eventos/ 
The title "A Quitna" shows raleway dots on firefox and on chrome shows raleway instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using Raleway Dots set the `font-weight: 400;` (not bold). This font-face doesn't have a bold version (see "style" section here https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Raleway+Dots - there is only "Regular").

Heading tags are usually bold by default so you have to explicitly set this.

Comment: That solved the problem. It was that simple and i didn't even notice. Thank you very much for your help :)